# Android WebView Post Request with Custom Headers how to do it

Tags: android, webview

For setting Headers

```
public void loadUrl (String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)  get request
```

For setting Post Data

```
public void postUrl (String url, byte[] postData)
```

don't add header

But what I really required is to post the data with headers.

Can somebody please help me out with that.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: The easiest solution would be to make this request from inside of the WebView, using JavaScript.